# Errors while compiling Dev-c++ tibia

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem while compiling my client with stians dev c++,

Some background i'm currently trying to change code in The forgottenserver.dev so it can allow me to level above 1million in a game called Tibia. I've changed the value from "uint64_t" To "uint128_t" in Player.h and player.cpp.
I've also changed in the protocolgame.cpp but that's just the exp limit

```
  if(experience > 2147483647) // client debugs after 2,147,483,647 exp
 msg->put<uint32_t>(2147483647);
```

So back to the problem, when im compiling im getting about 27-30 errors depends on what i try. Log:

```
    Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\444444444\trunk.r3884\dev-cpp\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\444444444\trunk.r3884\dev-cpp\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c ../actions.cpp -o obj//actions.o -I"C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/include/c++"  -D__USE_MYSQL__ -D__USE_SQLITE__ -D__ENABLE_SERVER_DIAGNOSTIC__ -O2   -fexpensive-optimizations -O1

In file included from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_duration_types.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:22,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:14,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/detail/select_reactor.hpp:25,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:27,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:550,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:20,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:24,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:25,
                 from C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/asio.hpp:20,
                 from ../otsystem.h:33,
                 from ../baseevents.h:20,
                 from ../actions.h:20,
                 from ../actions.cpp:20:

C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp: In static member function `static bool boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<ymd_type_, date_int_type_>::is_leap_year(typename ymd_type_::year_type) [with ymd_type_ = boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day, date_int_type_ = long unsigned int]':
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:182:   instantiated from `static short unsigned int boost::date_time::gregorian_calendar_base<ymd_type_, date_int_type_>::end_of_month_day(typename ymd_type_::year_type, typename ymd_type_::month_type) [with ymd_type_ = boost::gregorian::greg_year_month_day, date_int_type_ = long unsigned int]'
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_date.hpp:58:   instantiated from here
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator%' in 'year % 400'
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: note: candidates are: operator%(int, int) <built-in>
../uint128_t.h:373: note:                 T operator%(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::gregorian::greg_year]

C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator%' in 'year % 100'
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: note: candidates are: operator%(int, int) <built-in>
../uint128_t.h:373: note:                 T operator%(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::gregorian::greg_year]
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator%' in 'year % 4'
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/gregorian_calendar.ipp:167: note: candidates are: operator%(int, int) <built-in>
../uint128_t.h:373: note:                 T operator%(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::gregorian::greg_year]

In file included from ../player.h:23,
                 from ../actions.cpp:23:
../creature.h: In member function `virtual double Creature::getGainedExperience(Creature*) const':
../creature.h:355: error: conversion from `uint128_t' to `double' is ambiguous
../uint128_t.cpp:24: note: candidates are: uint128_t::operator bool() const
../uint128_t.cpp:28: note:                 uint128_t::operator char() const
../uint128_t.cpp:31: note:                 uint128_t::operator int() const
../uint128_t.cpp:35: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint8_t() const
../uint128_t.cpp:39: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint16_t() const
../uint128_t.cpp:43: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint32_t() const
../uint128_t.cpp:47: note:                 uint128_t::operator uint64_t() const

In file included from ../actions.cpp:24:
../monster.h: At global scope:
../monster.h:189: error: conflicting return type specified for `virtual uint64_t Monster::getLostExperience() const'

../creature.h:556: error:   overriding `virtual uint128_t Creature::getLostExperience() const'

In file included from ../scheduler.h:22,
                 from ../game.h:25,
                 from ../actions.cpp:30:
../dispatcher.h: In constructor `Task::Task(uint32_t, const boost::function<void ()()>&)':
../dispatcher.h:31: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/time.hpp:160: note: candidate 1: T boost::date_time::base_time<T, time_system>::operator+(const typename time_system::time_duration_type&) const [with T = boost::posix_time::ptime, time_system = boost::posix_time::posix_time_system]
../uint128_t.h:337: note: candidate 2: T operator+(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::system_time]

../uint128_t.h: In function `bool operator==(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::system_time]':
../dispatcher.h:39:   instantiated from here
../uint128_t.h:304: error: `const class boost::posix_time::ptime' used where a `uint64_t' was expected

../dispatcher.h: In member function `bool Task::hasExpired() const':
../dispatcher.h:42: error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
C:/Stian's Repack Dev-Cpp v2/Bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../../include/boost/date_time/time.hpp:130: note: candidate 1: bool boost::date_time::base_time<T, time_system>::operator<(const T&) const [with T = boost::posix_time::ptime, time_system = boost::posix_time::posix_time_system]

../uint128_t.h:315: note: candidate 2: bool operator<(const T&, const uint128_t&) [with T = boost::system_time]

make.exe: *** [obj//actions.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

I would love if someone could help me with this problem 
Regards,
Dennis

Edit:

```
    static uint64_t getExpForLevel(uint32_t lv) { static std::map<uint32_t, uint64_t> cache; lv--;

std::map<uint32_t, uint64_t>::iterator it = cache.find(lv); if(it != cache.end()) return it->second;

uint64_t exp = ((50ULL * (lv+1ULL) / 3ULL - 100ULL) * (lv+1ULL) + 850ULL / 3ULL) * (lv+1ULL) - 200ULL; cache[lv] = exp; return exp; }
```

Comment: One thing you can do to help both yourself and others trying to help is to try to find a minimal program that exhibits the same problem.  Sometimes you'll find your own problem while doing that (and learn a thing or two along the way.) If not, you're in better shape to have someone else see the problem.

Comment: FYI, the compiler is MinGW, not Dev-C++.  Dev-C++ is an IDE.  Your version seems to be pretty old, too.  If you actually have a compiler issue, it's probably not going to get fixed.

Comment: Looking again, why is it that you are trying to use uint128_t?  A 32-bit integer will hold values from -2 billion to +2 billion (plus a tad more on either end) and unsigned 32-bit integer will hold values from 0 to over 4 billion. A uint64_t will hold values your computer can't even count up to in your lifetime.

Comment: That's the kicker, i'm currently studying programming in sweden, and i've only learn C. The c++ course haven't started yet. So do you think that i only should change the value on Experience > 2147483647? I've also been told that Uint128_t will make it "easier" for me.

Comment: What do you suggest me to use to compile this, then?!

Comment: That 2147483647 is the actual maximum value that a signed (two's complement) 32 bit integer can hold.  What is that about?  It has nothing to do with "a maximum score of one millon" that I can see.  I can't see the code...and if it's the code for a whole game, I don't want to look at it.  That's what a minimal example will provide--a brief statement in code of what problem you are having that someone else can understand.

Comment: Should i post the whole code then? for player.h and player.cpp or even protocolgame.cpp?

Comment: WIth MinGW 3.x, I'm not sure if there even is an implementation of 128 bit integers. If the old code was working with 32 (or 64) bit integers, there is no reason to change types just to accommodate a value of one million.  That will easily fit in 32-bits.  You might need extra precision on some intermediate calculations, but that should be handled by those specific functions or methods that perform the computation.

Comment: So, yea it worked with 32 and 64 bit and i tried to change this

I have updated the main thread

This made me level to around 1million, and then it just stops.
23:37 You are level : ----> 1025743 <----

Comment: @mikehousky 
This is what someone told me
  "The max value of uint64_t is the max level that you reach right now and you can't just change to uint128_t to allow more levels because that don't exist by default so you have to code that.
You can check here that code already done and you have do add to your server:

http://www.codef00.com/code/uint128.h

Then you just need to change the type to uint128_t"